# Problem with blur and click event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web application with asp.net and at code behind with Jquery.

In that there are text boxes and a grid. There is written blur event in jquery page for the text boxes and row click event for the row in table.

When click the row then as per row value its details will displays in text boxes. My problem is that when I update the text box value (also that present in grid row) then goes in next text box then every thing will goes fine, blur event fires and data saved and will refresh if click on the grid row. But when i update something in text box and without pressing tab directly click on the grid row then blur event not fired and data not been saved directly click event fired and error comes when grid event calls. Also if I place debug point at the blur event and click event then the control comes in blur event, data will be saved but without firing row click event at that time.

What the problem occuring? ow to solves the problem? Any Idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just isolete the problem and show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the blur event which is only fired if an element on the page looses focus:

[jquery blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

You could try using the change event which will get fired only when the input areas value has changed.

[jquery change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Problem still occuring with the change event.